# RDS blue green switch failing with replication status

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, blue-green-deployment

I have a database cluster A in AWS RDS mysql aurora.

I create a blue green deployment that generates a database A-green. I choose "Switch" in the AWS UI. The switch fails and it shows in the logs:

`Switchover from DB cluster A to A-green was canceled due to external replication on A. Stop replication from an external database to A before you switch over.`

Where can I find this replication that the error talks about? I don't see anything in the console.

Also, `show slave status` returns empty

Cheers

Comment: Is the replication status for the green and blue DB clusters healthy? Amazon RDS runs the guardrail checks on the blue environment so you need to Make sure the blue DB cluster isn't the target of external replication to prevent writes on the blue DB cluster during the switchover.

Comment: Hi @ArpitJain, that's precisely my question. As far as I know my database is not the target of any replication. The console in AWS shows nothing. How can I find any information about this supposed replication?

Comment: Any read replica you have defined in the same or other regions?

Comment: @ArpitJain this cluster has one write instance. In the same region there is another cluster that has a writer and reader replica. But the replica is in a different cluster